# Unable to dismiss the modal view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Unable to dismiss modal view controller and return back to the root view controller. Animation did show but still pop out the current view controller.

I am developing app without using storyboard and i would like to dismiss the current modal view controller and back to root view controller.

is there any proper way to do this ?

My Root Controller is **Navigation Controller** While my modal View Controller is **UIViewController**. Is it the root cause for not working?

**Modal View Controller** (PlayerViewController)

```
func handleBack() {
    self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**FeedCell.swift in HomeController** (FeedCell.swift)

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let playerViewController = PlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**AppDelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout))

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 230, green: 32, blue: 31)

    // get rid of black bar underneath navbar
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),for: .default)

    application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    let statusBarBackgroundView = UIView()
    statusBarBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 194, green: 31, blue: 31)

    window?.addSubview(statusBarBackgroundView)
    window?.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: statusBarBackgroundView)
    window?.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(20)]", views: statusBarBackgroundView)

    return true
}
```

"Tapped" did showed but dismiss not working
[image]

Comment: post code, not picture

Comment: @Tj3n Done edited

Comment: post code adding back button in `Modal View Controller (PlayerViewController)

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout))
window?.rootViewController = navController
```

**Try this.**

Comment: Thanks, bro. Have amazing develop day.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to dismiss the current view controller that was presented as modal, you should invoke the one that presented the view controller and tell it to dismiss the presented view controller:

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

[presentingViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller):

> The view controller that presented this view controller.

Comment: You should invoke the call directly from the presented view controller which is the modal VC file.

Comment: still not working , still not working. My root controller is navigation controller and my modal view controller is UIViewController , is it possible the root cause for not working ?

Comment: First of all you should use the storyboard and not hard coded the actions you need. Looks like you need to debug the window class member inside the appDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss any viewController ,you should use

```
func handleBack() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
_ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```